# Formatting Multi-Field Labels in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

I am attempting to label parcels with information from two different fields, but I would like to format those labels separately for the sake of visual hierarchy.

I'm familiar with this expression: [Field1] & vbNewLine & [Field2] which shows the labels I want, in the order I want, but I do not know how to adjust the color/size/font of those labels individually.

The other option is to use the Maplex Lable engine to create classes for each field. This is good, as I can format the text the way I would like but then placement suffers, as I can't seem to recreate the centered, two-line look that the code above produces. For example, setting internal placement rules for the two classes works for small parcels, as they're still grouped together, but falls apart for larger parcels, where the labels get separated.

[image: You can see in the photo that separate classes method works OK in smaller parcels, but starts to fall apart in larger ones. It seems you can only adjust relative to the polygon (which is tough when they're all such different sizes), and can't specify an amount of offset.]

There are two paths to solve this and I would welcome suggestions for either one: code suggestions for formatting within the expression, so everything can be done in one go, or tips for being more fine-grained with label placement in the label engine (for example, if I recall correctly QGIS has the ability to place labels by a specified offset on a specified axis...this would solve the problem but I'm not sure how to do something similar in ArcMap).

Comment: I would have a look at this link: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm with your example it might be something like: [Field1] & vbNewLine & <FNT name = "Arial" size = "8"><CLR red = '100' green = '100' blue = '100'>[Field2] <CLR><FNT>

Comment: This worked great. Thank you for introducing me to this. The code I used:        "<BOL>" & "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '9'>" & [TRACT_ID] & "</FNT>"  & "</BOL>" & vbNewLine & "<CLR black = '60'>" & "<ITA>" & "<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '6'>" & [APN] & "</FNT>" & "</ITA>" & "</CLR>"

Comment: Cool I will post my comment as an answer. Something to consider...I don't think you need to ampersands (&) in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at this link: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm

It describes the syntax ArcMap uses to apply text formatting to text in ArcMap.

With your example it might be something like:

```
[Field1] & vbNewLine & <FNT name = "Arial" size = "8"><CLR red = '100' green = '100' blue = '100'>[Field2] <CLR><FNT>
```